# Content following bibliography still has bibliography header

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

Writing in book class, I have a chapter, full of good things, followed by a bibliography.  After the bibliography is a section for problems and examples.  My issue is that the problems and examples section inherits the header structure from the bibliography, specifically, it displays "Bibliography" in the header.

I have attempted to use fancyhdr package with \thispagestyle{plain}, but it only changes the first page, and does not reset the header to the rest of the chapter.

mwe:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}

% General
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}       % Fancy chapter (headings)
\usepackage[bindingoffset=2cm,margin=2cm]{geometry} % Page dimensions
\usepackage{tabto}                  % Absolute positioning
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}               % Space bn paragraphs

% Bibliography
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}     % Citation management

\begin{document}

\chapter{It's a Chapter!}
\section{With Some Sections}
\label{sec: With Some Sections}

And text!

I do not clearly remember the arrival of the curate, so that probably I dozed. I became aware of him as a seated figure in soot-smudged shirt sleeves, and with his upturned, clean-shaven face staring at a faint flickering that danced over the sky. The sky was what is called a mackerel sky--rows and rows of faint down-plumes of cloud, just tinted with the midsummer sunset. I sat up, and at the rustle of my motion he looked at me quickly. "Have you any water?" I asked abruptly. He shook his head. "You have been asking for water for the last hour," he said. For a moment we were silent, taking stock of each other. I dare say he found me a strange enough figure, naked, save for my water-soaked trousers and socks, scalded, and my face and shoulders blackened by the smoke. His face was a fair weakness, his chin retreated, and his hair lay in crisp, almost flaxen curls on his low forehead; his eyes were rather large, pale blue, and blankly staring. He spoke abruptly, looking vacantly away from me. "What does it mean?" he said. -- HG Wells \cite{hg11987}

\nocite{hg21987}
\nocite{hg31987}

\clearpage 
\raggedbottom
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{test}

\clearpage
\noindent \textbf{Problems}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Problem One
\item Problem Two
\item Problem Three
\item Problem Four
\item Problem Five
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: Bibliography]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want all the pages following the bibliography to have the headers of the previous chapter and section, you can add the lines

```
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \ It's a Chapter!}}%
         {\MakeUppercase{\thesection. \ With Some Sections}}
```

after your bibliography, assuming that "It's a Chapter!" is the title of your last chapter and "With Some Sections" is the title of your last section.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}

% General
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}       % Fancy chapter (headings)
\usepackage[bindingoffset=2cm,margin=2cm]{geometry} % Page dimensions
\usepackage{tabto}                  % Absolute positioning
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}               % Space bn paragraphs

% Bibliography
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}     % Citation management

\usepackage{lipsum}                  % just for the example

\begin{document}

\chapter{It's a Chapter!}
\section{With Some Sections}
\label{sec: With Some Sections}

And text!

I do not clearly remember the arrival of the curate, so that probably I
dozed. I became aware of him as a seated figure in soot-smudged shirt
sleeves, and with his upturned, clean-shaven face staring at a faint
flickering that danced over the sky. The sky was what is called a mackerel
sky--rows and rows of faint down-plumes of cloud, just tinted with the
midsummer sunset. I sat up, and at the rustle of my motion he looked at me
quickly. "Have you any water?" I asked abruptly. He shook his head. "You have
been asking for water for the last hour," he said. For a moment we were
silent, taking stock of each other. I dare say he found me a strange enough
figure, naked, save for my water-soaked trousers and socks, scalded, and my
face and shoulders blackened by the smoke. His face was a fair weakness, his
chin retreated, and his hair lay in crisp, almost flaxen curls on his low
forehead; his eyes were rather large, pale blue, and blankly staring. He
spoke abruptly, looking vacantly away from me. "What does it mean?" he said.
-- HG Wells \cite{hg11987}

\nocite{hg21987}
\nocite{hg31987}

\clearpage
\raggedbottom
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{test}

\clearpage
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \ It's a Chapter!}}%
         {\MakeUppercase{\thesection. \ With Some Sections}}    
\noindent \textbf{Problems}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Problem One
\item Problem Two
\item Problem Three
\item Problem Four
\item Problem Five
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Output (pages following the bibliography):

[image]

Comment: I would consider that a fix I would 'settle' for, but I prefer to restore the chapter headings.

Comment: @Ish you have no chapter after the bibliography. What chapter are you referring to, the one preceeding the bibliography?

Comment: Yes, the problem set is part of the existing chapter.

Comment: @Ish answer edited...